# PNP app only authentication with certificate : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.' category="invalid_client

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, pnp, azure

I've been trying for age to use azure authentication with a certificate to retrieve a usable clientcontext to do some csom operation but not matter the method I try I always get the same error message when trying to execute a query : 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized'

I created an app registration from Azure's active directory, created a certificate following  [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) and uploaded it on azure. I allowed client flows, gave all the sharepoint permissions I could think of but there is no helping it, unauthorized always pops up.

I tried multiple method from multiple tutorials, here's the simplest :

```
public static ClientContext getContext()
    {
        var authManager = AuthenticationManager.CreateWithCertificate("****-4aeb-4462-af2e-117923bc30ea", "C:\\Users\\Hadrien\\MyAppCertificate.pfx", "<<CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD>>", "a0e03199-****-****-8e54-829a3ba6d5c0", null, AzureEnvironment.Production, null);
        context = authManager.GetContext("https://1ntermade.sharepoint.com/sites/CircuitFoilWS/");
        context.Load(context.web);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        return context;
    }
```

Since I tried different ways to get the context and none work, I guess the problem come from the way I configured Azure, but I think I exhausted all the tutorial on google without finding the answer ...

here's the error message in full :

```
_httpResponseMessage    {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent,
Headers:
{
  P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
  Set-Cookie: SPWorkLoadAttribution=Url=https://myorg.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery&AppId=E0D3C05D-9133-40D1-8413-1C4522A4E7C2; expires=Fri, 14-Oct-2022 09:09:25 GMT; path=/
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="a0e03199-723d-4d35-8e54-829a3ba6d5c0",client_id="00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*,D3776938-3DBA-481F-A652-4BEDFCAB7CD8@*,https://sts.windows.net/*/,00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@90140122-8516-11e1-8eff-49304924019b",authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize"
  x-ms-diagnostics: 3001000;reason="There has been an error authenticating the request.";category="invalid_client"
  X-DataBoundary: None
  X-1DSCollectorUrl: https://eu-mobile.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0/
  X-AriaCollectorURL: https://eu-mobile.events.data.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0
  SPRequestGuid: dc7e6ea0-00a8-5000-3690-c09c12bf5f08
  request-id: dc7e6ea0-00a8-5000-3690-c09c12bf5f08
  MS-CV: oG5+3KgAAFA2kMCcEr9fCA.0
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com *.dynamics.com *.microsoft.com securebroker.sharepointonline.com;
  SPRequestDuration: 28
  SPIisLatency: 0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.22928
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
  X-Cache: CONFIG_NOCACHE
  X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 9360C07B9CD6443D95B6110532AC6412 Ref B: AMS04EDGE3117 Ref C: 2022-10-14T09:08:55Z
  Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2022 09:08:55 GMT
  Content-Length: 74
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
```